# I've deleted master branch on my local phpstorm

Tags: git, phpstorm

i'm new to phpstorm I've deleted master branch on my local phpstorm.
How can i recreate it on phpstorm

Comment: like how do i do that

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you deleted it and what have you done afterwards...

But the easiest and safest is to:

1. Use `git reflog` to find last commit of master branch.
2. Use `git checkout HEAD@{X}` to go to that last commit. If you haven't done anything after deleting it, X is 1.
3. Use `git checkout -b master` to create a master branch on that commit.

Optionally you want to set up tracking if you're using a remote repository (e.g. origin):

```
git branch --track master origin/master
```